# Understanding Array function definitions: How to make [Word8] into Array (Int, Int) Word8

Tags: arrays, haskell

so I have a function, called `funcA`.

Here is the "definition" (I'm just getting started with learning Haskell).

```
funcA :: Quadtree -> Array (Int, Int) Word8
```

An example would be taking `Quadtree` and returning this, as a Working Solution:

```
listArray ((0,0), (2,2)) [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]
```

I am currently returning `[Word8]`. My question is, isn't `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]` a `[Word8]`, not `Word8`? So, our working solution is of the form `Array (Int, Int) [Word8]`, right? It does not follow the function definition's return format?

How do I take `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]` which is a `[Word8]` and make it of the form `Array (Int, Int) Word8`?

Answer (score 5):

`listArray` has this type:

```
listArray :: Ix i => (i, i) -> [e] -> Array i e
```

We can match this up to your expression:

```
listArray ((0,0), (2,2)) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

by matching the arguments with their types, making the following typing decisions:

```
((0,0), (2,2)) :: (i, i)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] :: [e]
listArray ((0,0), (2,2)) [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] :: Array i e
```

It's not hard to see that `i` is `(Int, Int)` (or any other `(a, a)` where `a` is some instance of `Num`... but it looks like you're expecting `Int`, so that's fine).  And that `e` is `Word8` (or, again, any other `Num` instance).

So yes, it's true that `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] :: [Word8]`.  But the parameter type is `[e]` rather than just `e`, and that means that the `e` type variable unifies with the element type, `Word8`.  Plugging that into the type of `listArray`, you'll see that the result type is `Array (Int, Int) Word8` as expected.

Comment: Thanks. How is `(0,0)` and `(3,3)` an `Int`? According to the site (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Int.html), an `Int` is "A fixed-precision integer type with at least the range [-2^29 .. 2^29-1]". So shouldn't it be `Array ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) Word8`?